# vb.net cannot connect to sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net

I am trying to make a login database using vb.net. I am using this code to connect but it doesn't work!:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim rd As SqlDataReader




        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=user; Integrated Security= true"
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "select login, password from auth where login= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "' "

        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rd.HasRows Then
            Welcome.Show()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed", "error")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have a data base on my sql server called "user" and in user there is a table named "dbo.auth". When I click Label2, visual basic says "con cannot be opened" I am using MySQL server workbench. Is there any way I can fix this? The server is also running on my local network.

Comment: `MySql` <> `Sql`, please decide and determine what DBMS you are using. Also you are using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` namespaces, if you are using `MySql` these are wrong. You need to use `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` namespaces. IMO there are other issues (not disposing objects, etc), but they are not your issue you are seeing.

Comment: To expand on what @Codexer said, the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace is for SQL Server specifically. If you're using MySQL then you need to download Connector/Net from MySQL and use members of the `MySQL.Data.MySqlClient` namespace. I would imagine that there's a relevant NuGet package, or you can install it from the MySQL web site and add references manually. You'll also need to make sure to use a [MySQL-specific connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/).

Comment: There should be a nuget package for MySQLClient. Check under the Tools menu for Nuget Package Manager => Manage Nuget Packages for Solution

Comment: Please don't concatenate strings for .CommandText. You are open to SQL Injection. Use Parameters.

Comment: To ensure that objects that have a .Dispose method are closed and disposed properly use Using...End Using blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class LoginForm1
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    ' TODO: Insert code to perform custom authentication using the provided username and password 
    ' (See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=35339).  
    ' The custom principal can then be attached to the current thread's principal as follows: 
    '     My.User.CurrentPrincipal = CustomPrincipal
    ' where CustomPrincipal is the IPrincipal implementation used to perform authentication. 
    ' Subsequently, My.User will return identity information encapsulated in the CustomPrincipal object
    ' such as the username, display name, etc.

    Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        conn = New SqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
        Try
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Connected!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
     End Sub
```

Also, I think you should bookmark the link below.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/